# How can I view comments I have made to various posts from the one Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I want to look back at comments I have made to a specific Facebook page for the past 3 years. It is a business's page, not a group.
None of the efforts I have made searching the Activity Log have borne fruit. Are you able to help?

Comment: What are the ways you already have tried? If you will mention, it will be helpful to us to provide different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Facebook search using an intersection of the stories by the page against comments made by you.

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/PAGE_ID/stories-by/USER_ID/stories-commented/intersect`